# Get USB Mass Storage Devices with Addresses in C++ on Linux with Codeblocks

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, codeblocks

I am new to the whole linux and c/c++ development world and I'm trying to port one of my windows programs to Linux. I am stuck at figuring out how to get USB Devices like memory sticks, external hard drives that are connected to the system as well as their addresses so that they can be used with certain commandline utilities.

My development environment:

- **OS:** Zorin OS 15 64-bit
- **IDE:** Code::Blocks 16
- **Compiler:** GCC
- **GUI:** WxWidgets 3
- **Development Language:** C++

I know on windows you can use GetLogicalDrives() to get the drives that are attached to the system and in such a way determine if the device is USB or not. I have tried to use libusb (with it's header file), but cannot figure out how to get the devices and add them to a dropdown box.

I have used the following code from the libusb docs:

```
static void print_devs(libusb_device **devs)
{
    libusb_device *dev;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    uint8_t path[8]; 

    while ((dev = devs[i++]) != NULL) {
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
        if (r < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to get device descriptor");
            return;
        }

        printf("%04x:%04x (bus %d, device %d)",
            desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct,
            libusb_get_bus_number(dev), libusb_get_device_address(dev));

        r = libusb_get_port_numbers(dev, path, sizeof(path));
        if (r > 0) {
            printf(" path: %d", path[0]);
            for (j = 1; j < r; j++)
                printf(".%d", path[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

but this give me the following error: `undefined reference to 'libusb_get_device_descriptor'`.

I have included the `libusb.h` file as well as `libusb.a` and `libusb.so`.

All I want to do is get a list of attached removable usb drives with their addresses (in the form of **/dev/sda** or similar) so that I can add them to the dropdown box for later use.

When all is said and done, the user will select a USB drive from the drop down, then the app will format the device if the user chooses to do so and then copy some files onto it.

**EDIT:**

Here is the output of the build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in BlackBoxISOBeta (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++  -o bin/Debug/BlackBoxISOBeta obj/Debug/BlackBoxISOBetaApp.o obj/Debug/BlackBoxISOBetaMain.o obj/Debug/BurnUSB.o  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread   -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.a
obj/Debug/BurnUSB.o: In function `print_devs(libusb_device**)':
/home/mafiafly/Documents/bbiso/BlackBoxISOBeta/BurnUSB.cpp:56: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
/home/mafiafly/Documents/bbiso/BlackBoxISOBeta/BurnUSB.cpp:64: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_address'
/home/mafiafly/Documents/bbiso/BlackBoxISOBeta/BurnUSB.cpp:64: undefined reference to `libusb_get_bus_number'
/home/mafiafly/Documents/bbiso/BlackBoxISOBeta/BurnUSB.cpp:66: undefined reference to `libusb_get_port_numbers'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I get the same error with `libusb.a` and `libusb.so`

Comment: Where did you add the libusb library to your program?

Comment: I added it under the Linker section of codeblocks

Comment: What did you put in the linker section? It seems that the linker section is wrong.

Comment: I cannot post a screenshot now, but in the linker section under link libraries, I have added the following paths: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.so and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb.a. I have verified that both files exist and if I use another lib like libburn, it works

Comment: Many Linux distributions install multiple versions of libusb under different names. Fedora, for example, installs libusb-0.1 and libusb-1.0. You're linking with the wrong one.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik on my system I've got the above mentioned files as well as one named libusb-1.0.so.0. Which one would be the correct one?

Comment: Is something preventing you from trying to link with each one, in turn, until it succeeds?

Comment: In codeblocks, only the libusb.so and libusb.a files show up if I try to link them in the linker section. The libusb-1.0.so.0 file doesn't show

Comment: Adding both .so and .a files to the list of libraries is definitely wrong. Perhaps you are adding them to a wrong place. Show your build **log**.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. added the log to the post

Comment: What happens if you use `-lusb` instead of the full path to libusb? That's what you do with all other libraries.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. same error as before

Comment: It looks like you need `-lusb-1.0` and not `-lusb`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. now it gives a new error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0`

Comment: This is strange. You do have libusb-1.0.so.0. What kind of file is this? Is this a symlink? What it points at? Also, you #include libusb.h, what is the full path to it?